# What happens when you delete GUID_Partion_Scheme?

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, partition, diskutil

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         121.1 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.1 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     67.6 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 408.1 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                622.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      4.3 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            22.1 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 22.1 GB    disk1s5s1
```

Answer (score 1):

`GUID_partition_scheme` is the human-readable label for the [**GUID Partition Table (GPT)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) that resides near the beginning of your disk and describes the physical partitions contained within it. Deleting it would cause the entirety of all data on your drive to no longer be accessible without recovery tools. macOS will see an uninitialized disk and ask if you would like to format it.

Comment: Well, near the beginning with an exact copy near the end. (The table entries are the same, but the headers are different.)

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, this is the part of the disk that describes what all the rest of this disk is going to be.
It is, in effect, "the whole disk". You can see its size is the entire size of the disk itself - give or take some 'administrative details'.

Everything else you see on it starts from there, as a 'map' of what all the other parts are for & where they live.

You can't really delete it like you could delete a partition. It's made when you format the whole disk. Removing it or reformatting would remove all the existing pointers to where everything else is. It wouldn't actually delete it, but it would make it all very difficult to find again.
The Mac would see a blank disk.